# Redirect only Directory to Subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I struggle with a .htaccess problem and hope you can help me:

The following URL needs to be forwarded to a subdirectory located INSIDE this directory.

```
https://my.domain/calendar
```

In '/calendar' I have a subdir for each year. So currently I need a forwarding to:

```
https://my.domain/calendar/2017
```

Any other URLs in /calendar shall remain as they are (e.g. my.domain/calendar/this-is-a-date).

I tried different 'standard' redirects with Redirect, RewriteRule etc. but none of them worked. The results were 500er Errors or infinite redirects.

How do I solve this problem in my .htaccess file?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^calendar/?$ /calendar/2017` ?

Comment: Oh yeah! I've forgotten to set the regex parts. Now it works, thanks!